# one Xcode with two targets - but different selection of Localizable.string files

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is it possible to somehow associate different localizable.strings files to different targets of the same project.

For example:

target1 has English and French while target 2 has English and German ?

For "normal" files like the *.m or *.h one can set the Target Membership - but I did not find something for the different language specific Localizable.strings files.

I guess if this is not possible I really have to manually configure the Localizable.strings files before I create the ipa for submission - which is surely not the best thinkable approach.

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm able to select the target membership for Localizable.strings at File Inspector, don't you see this section ? Maybe you've collapsed  it ?

Comment: Please make a fancy screenshot and answer the question, it should not be unanswered as you know yourself, and there was no significant effort from me so that's OK.

Comment: Yes, could you please write your comment in the answer so I can check it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the section es expanded, you should see the Target Membership section like you used to for other files:

[image]